# Make tabs in Tkinter GUI using notebook

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to make a GUI in Tkinter, want the GUI to have 2 tabs. I am using `ttk.notebook` for that.

My code is as follows:

```
root=tk.Tk()
root.title("Data Tool")
root.geometry("500x300")

nb = ttk.Notebook(root)

nb.place(relx=0,rely=0)

# Adds tab 1 of the notebook
page1 = ttk.Frame(nb)
nb.add(page1, text='Home')

# Adds tab 2 of the notebook
page2 = ttk.Frame(nb)
nb.add(page2, text='Tool')


tk.Label(page1,text="test",bg="red").place(relx=0.2,rely=0.4)

root.mainloop()
```

This GUI is not showing the label on page1. What could be wrong in the code?

Comment: If you're just a beginner, I _strongly_ encourage you to avoid the use of `place`. It makes coding more difficult. Instead, learn how to use `grid` and `pack`. Your application will be much more responsive.

Comment: Sure. I use `place` because widgets can be placed at any place in the GUI. Initially, I faced problem with pack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your label's master is set to `page1` which is an empty frame, and then you call `place` on the label using `relx` and `rely`. To show the widget, your frame need to have a size:

```
page1 = ttk.Frame(nb,height=400,width=400)
```